# Will Salesforce release an ios16 beta compatible update?

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

Salesforce currently does not support ios16. Will it be updated soon to be compatible or not until the fall when it’s officially released?

Comment: Do note that this isn't an official support channel for Salesforce (except for the mobile SDK team, maybe?). Most of us are just end-users volunteering our time and knowledge.

Comment: Hi @Francine, I have checked with our Salesforce Product team regarding your ask. As per the update from them, the upcoming app version that would be rolling out now 238.030 is known to work in iOS 16. Can you try manually updating to the latest version.

Comment: Hi @SaiPraveenKakkirala, I manually updated and it now works. Thank you so much for taking the time to ask your team and provide me with an update. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Francine, Thanks for confirmation I will post the same as answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments I have checked with our Salesforce Product team regarding your ask. As per the update from them, the upcoming app version that would be rolling out now 238.030 is known to work in iOS 16. Can you try manually updating to the latest version